# Video site using Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

Want to build a video site like YouTube or peer tube but on my lan completely private, basically I want to pretend my kids are online when their not... plus a good project to learn.

Answer (score 1):

A video based website would be easy to make. You could do this quite easily with a few Wagtail Pages, uploading videos as Documents and using a DocumentChooserPanel to select a video on each page.

To get started you'll want to start in two places:

1. The wagtail docs, available at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html, and
2. For additional tutorials https://wagtail.io/course/

Take it slow at first, get your virtual environment setup. Then move on to creating your first Wagtail Home Page and adding a few custom fields, then make them show up in the `home_page.html` template.

For future reference, when you ask questions on StackOverflow (or anywhere else) make sure you add more detail to your question. Including what you've done/tried so far, your end goal, or any problematic code you're working on will help you get answers faster and it'll generate better answers than mine.